# Computing $\langle (13746) \rangle$ in $S_7$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

How to list the elements of subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ in $S^7$ where $$a=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 3 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 &4 \end{pmatrix}?$$  I got $a=(13746)(2)(5)$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's a correct representation. The form $a=(13746)(2)(5)$ is called cyclic form.

Comment: You already have $1,a\in\langle a\rangle$. So you have to compute the rest of the permutations by hand: $a^2$, $a^3$, $a^4$, $\dots$.

Comment: James: it's a good idea to consider "accepting" an answer if it's been helpful. You can accept exactly ONE answer per question, and you can do so by clicking on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept!

Answer (score 1):

First $1$ goes to $3$, then it goes to $7$, then it goes to $4$, then it goes to $6$, then it goes to $1$.  In cycle notation that's $(13746)$.  $2$ and $5$ are fixed, so there's no need to think about them.

So, let's calculate $a^2$.  $1$ skips over $3$ and goes to $7$, which skips over $4$ to get to $6$, which skips over $1$ to get to $3$, which skips over $7$ to get to $4$, then back to $1$.  So $a^2=(17634)$.

In the same way, we get that $a^3=(14367)$.

Now you try for $a^4$.

Then, I claim that $a^5$ is the identity. Why?

That brings us to $\langle a \rangle = \{\operatorname{id},(13746),(17634),(14367),a^4\}$ (where you calculate $a^4$).

Comment: Thank you Alexander! I got a^4 to be (16473)

Comment: @JamesBond That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of $a$ is correct, but (2) and (5) need not be written out. To find the elements of the subgroup, first calculate $a^2 = (1 7 6 3 4)$, then $a^3$, $a^4$, and so on until you get the identity element (1). There won't be very many calculations...

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$
a=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 3 & 2 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
$, which can be expressed as $a=(13746)\\$.

Then $a^2=(13746)(13746)=(17634)\\$.
Similarly, $a^3=(17634)(17634)=(16473)$. We see that the $n^{th}$ power of $a$ takes the entry in the $i^{th}$ position of $a$ to the entry in $i+1^{th}$ entry of $a$.

Since $a^5$ brings each entry of $a$ back to its original location, it is the identity, and $|a|=|⟨a⟩|=5$.